# Set Filename Storage::put

Tags: laravel

I cant set a filename with Storage::put in Laravel 5.8

I tried the following:

`Storage::put(private/foo/bar , $file, 'private');`
This is creating the folder structure with a random generated filename inside. (Like: private/foo/bar/uidjasbknfsdoiruewjnfsdai.pdf)

`Storage::put(private/foo/bar/file.pdf , $file, 'private');`
This is creating this: private/foo/bar/file.pdf/uidjasbknfsdoiruewjnfsdai.pdf

I expect my own given filename on this private file. The file should not be public.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to upload a file on my Google Drive using laravel and was able to maintain it's original filename using the code below:

```
if($file = $request->file('my_file')){
   $filename_server = Storage::disk('google')
   ->putFileAs('/MyFolder', $file, $file->getClientOriginalName());
}
```

Previously, when using `putFile`, my uploaded file was automatically being renamed with some alphanumeric characters.

But when I used `putFileAs`, I was able to preserved the original filename on the google drive folder.

Answer (score 0):

According to Laravel docs:

> If you would not like a file name to be automatically assigned to your stored file, you may use the storeAs method, which receives the path, the file name, and the (optional) disk as its arguments:

```php
$path = $request->file('avatar')->storeAs(
    'avatars', $request->user()->id
);
```

> You may also use the putFileAs method on the Storage facade, which will perform the same file manipulation as the example above:

```php
$path = Storage::putFileAs(
    'avatars', $request->file('avatar'), $request->user()->id
);
```

The third argument for the `putFileAs` is the visibility of the file. If you would like every users can access it, use `public` instead of `$request->user()->id`.

You can [read more here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#file-uploads).